# Sumar valores cumpliendo dos criterios

Tags: r

Escribo para pedirle ayuda en esto:

[image: ggp]

tengo un dataframe con 3 variables y quiero sumar el valor teniendo en cuenta la secuencia y el producto, puede ser usando la función agregate y quede de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
UNICOS <- aggregate(Secuencia ~ Producto, Atencion, function(x), length(unique(x))
    UNICOS <- UNICOS[order(-UNICOS$Secuencia), ]
    UNICOS$Producto <- factor(UNICOS$Producto, levels=UNICOS$Producto, ordered = TRUE
```

Tengo este código pero como ven este tiene en cuenta 2 variables, me cuenta los valores únicos según la secuencia, hora necesito que me sume los precios de la misma secuencia y con igual nombre.

Comment: Hola Lina, Con `agregate` lo podrías resolver, pero no entiendo cual es la pregunta o el inconveniente que tienes?

Comment: Hola deje el código arriba,  pero como ven este tiene en cuenta 2 variables, me cuenta los valores únicos según la secuencia, ahora necesito que me sume los precios de la misma secuencia y con igual nombre.

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución:

```
Secuencia <- c(654885, 7709,654885, 987, 987)
Producto <- c("Beer", "Hot dog","Beer", "Sandwich", "Sandwich")
Valor <- c(5000, 7000, 15000, 10000, 20000)

Atencion <- data.frame(Secuencia, Producto, Valor)

aggregate(Valor ~ Producto + Secuencia, data = Atencion, FUN = sum)
```

Mediante la función `aggregate`, a la variable valor se la particiona por cada categoría de Producto *y* Secuencia y se realiza la suma.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It run perfect

Comment: Solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!